# How to use Soap extensions at client application

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I crate one webservice using c#.For encrypting response, using the dll specified in this article

http://highcoding.blogspot.in/

WebMetod

```
[WebMethod]
[EncryptionExtension(Decrypt = DecryptMode.None, Encrypt = EncryptMode.Response, Target = Target.Body)]
[TracingExtension(TracingMode = TracingMode.Response, MethodName = "HelloWorld")]
public string HelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

I created one webservice client using c# windows application.

```
   ServiceReference1.ServiceSoapClient ob = new WindowsFormsApplication2.ServiceReference1.ServiceSoapClient();
        string st = ob.HelloWorld();
```

Here i getting an error "End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected"

Encryption is working.But i tried and dont able to find out a way to  decrypt data at client side .Anyone know how to handle this in client?

Answer (score 0):

At your proxy client code, add the 'EncryptionExtension' attribute to HelloWorld method

```
[EncryptionExtension(Decrypt = DecryptMode.Response, Encrypt = EncryptMode.None, Target = Target.Body)]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke("HelloWorld", new object[] { });
    return ((string)(results[0]));
}
```

BEWARE, this proxy is auto-generated code. Every time you make changes to the webservice, it will be regenerated and your changes will be lost.

Best way to handling this situation is configuration soap extension through configuration. Please follow this link on how to do it.

http://fluentbytes.com/applying-soap-extension-client-proxy-without-altering-generated-proxy-code/

Comment: Where i need to put this code..i tried it by adding in reference.cs file..its not working

Comment: Where to define this "Invoke" method??

Comment: i got an error like this..does not contain a definition for 'Invoke' and no extension method 'Invoke' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication2.ServiceReference1.ServiceSoapClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: ya..its working.earlier i added service references.its working after adding it as WebReference

Comment: In your webreference (Reference.cs) file, look for method HelloWorld(). Add [EncryptionExtension(Decrypt = DecryptMode.Response, Encrypt = EncryptMode.None, Target = Target.Body)] there.

Comment: u suggested one more option "configuration soap extension through configuration".  where i need to put these lines".Is it to be added in app.config in windows client app or web.config file in WebService ??

Comment: In app.config in your windows client app. But found a bug in  SoapExtensions.dll when using this method. Config looks below

  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <soapExtensionTypes>
        <add type="SoapExtensions.EncryptionExtension, SoapExtensions" />
      </soapExtensionTypes>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>

Comment: In EncryptionExtension.cs file, modify the GetInitializer() as below

        public override object GetInitializer(Type serviceType)
        {
            EncryptionExtensionAttribute ext = new EncryptionExtensionAttribute();
            ext.Decrypt = DecryptMode.Response;
            ext.Encrypt = EncryptMode.Request;
            ext.Target = Target.Body;
            return ext;
        }

Comment: ..I tried to override  public override object GetInitializer(Type serviceType)..but it is not working..excution is not reaching at this function